# I have a JSON package and I need to display the data in it in my application, how can I do that?

Tags: android, json, database, api, kotlin

I am making an application about solar panels and I need to pull the status and efficiency of solar panels from the database with the help of API. I found a site, but I couldn't find the API file in it, it only offers JSON packages specific to the region I selected. How can I pull data with JSON package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to use JSON and Okhttp in Kotlin

First, add dependencies of Okhttp to your project, then create an object from `OKHTTPCLIENT()` like this:

```
val client = OKHTTPCLIENT()

val request = Request.Builder()
.url("URL OF JSON")
.build()
```

Next, add these following lines of code to `onResponse` funtion:

```
val rawContent = response.body!!.string()
val jsonObject = JSONOBJECT(rawContent)
jsonObject.getInt("ID OF content u want")
```

Now you have a JSON object there

JSON Docs here :
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/org/json/JSONObject